# Different coefficient estimates from ncvreg and glmnet in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, glmnet

I'm trying to compare the results from `glmnet` and `ncvreg` in logistic regression. The methods have **similar** coefficients estimates in the case of lasso (`alpha=1`). It seems they are very different for the other values of `alpha`. The difference increase as `alpha` value gets smaller. I have attached the estimates resulted for `alpha=1,0.7,0.2,0.01`.

I believe that both of the methods use the same loss function and penalty function. Both of the packages standardize the predictors first, obtain the coefficient estimates and scale the coefficients to the original scale.

What is the reason for the different coefficient esimates?

```
library(ncvreg)
library(glmnet)

# Binomial
data(Heart)
X <- Heart$X
y <- Heart$y
n <- nrow(X)
lambda <- 0.05

# Lasso
alpha <- 1

fitncv <- ncvreg(X,y,family='binomial',penalty="lasso",alpha=alpha,eps=1e-7)
bncvreg <- as.matrix(coef(fitncv, lambda=lambda))

fitgnet <- glmnet(X,y,"binomial",alpha=alpha,thresh=1e-7)
bgnet <- coef(fitgnet,s=lambda,exact=TRUE,x=X,y=y)
# 
comb <- round(cbind(bncvreg,bgnet,bncvreg-bgnet), 5)
colnames(comb) <- c("ncvreg","glmnet","difference")

#               ncvreg   glmnet difference
# (Intercept) -2.93145 -2.93089   -0.00056
# sbp          0.00000  0.00000    0.00000
# tobacco      0.04127  0.04128   -0.00001
# ldl          0.07530  0.07531   -0.00001
# adiposity    0.00000  0.00000    0.00000
# famhist      0.47198  0.47198    0.00000
# typea        0.00356  0.00355    0.00001
# obesity      0.00000  0.00000    0.00000
# alcohol      0.00000  0.00000    0.00000
# age          0.03093  0.03092    0.00001


# enet
alpha <- 0.7

fitncv <- ncvreg(X,y,family='binomial',penalty="lasso",alpha=alpha,eps=1e-10)
bncvreg <- as.matrix(coef(fitncv, lambda=lambda))

fitgnet <- glmnet(X,y,"binomial",alpha=alpha)
bgnet <- coef(fitgnet,s=lambda,exact=TRUE,x=X,y=y)
# 
comb <- round(cbind(bncvreg,bgnet,bncvreg-bgnet), 5)
colnames(comb) <- c("ncvreg","glmnet","difference")

#               ncvreg   glmnet difference
# (Intercept) -3.74974 -3.58243   -0.16731
# sbp          0.00000  0.00023   -0.00023
# tobacco      0.05106  0.05067    0.00039
# ldl          0.09722  0.09553    0.00169
# adiposity    0.00000  0.00000    0.00000
# famhist      0.57815  0.55639    0.02175
# typea        0.01169  0.01056    0.00113
# obesity      0.00000  0.00000    0.00000
# alcohol      0.00000  0.00000    0.00000
# age          0.03495  0.03239    0.00256

# enet2
alpha <- 0.2

fitncv <- ncvreg(X,y,family='binomial',penalty="lasso",alpha=alpha,eps=1e-10)
bncvreg <- as.matrix(coef(fitncv, lambda=lambda))

fitgnet <- glmnet(X,y,"binomial",alpha=alpha)
bgnet <- coef(fitgnet,s=lambda,exact=TRUE,x=X,y=y)
# 
comb <- round(cbind(bncvreg,bgnet,bncvreg-bgnet), 5)
colnames(comb) <- c("ncvreg","glmnet","difference")

#               ncvreg   glmnet difference
# (Intercept) -5.58114 -4.97611   -0.60503
# sbp          0.00425  0.00463   -0.00038
# tobacco      0.06902  0.06441    0.00461
# ldl          0.14270  0.12517    0.01753
# adiposity    0.00000  0.00440   -0.00440
# famhist      0.78153  0.68973    0.09180
# typea        0.02781  0.02175    0.00606
# obesity     -0.01339 -0.00894   -0.00444
# alcohol      0.00000  0.00000    0.00000
# age          0.04196  0.03301    0.00895

# enet3
alpha <- 0.01

fitncv <- ncvreg(X,y,family='binomial',penalty="lasso",alpha=alpha,eps=1e-10)
bncvreg <- as.matrix(coef(fitncv, lambda=lambda))

fitgnet <- glmnet(X,y,"binomial",alpha=alpha)
bgnet <- coef(fitgnet,s=lambda,exact=TRUE,x=X,y=y)
# 
comb <- round(cbind(bncvreg,bgnet,bncvreg-bgnet), 5)
colnames(comb) <- c("ncvreg","glmnet","difference")

#               ncvreg   glmnet difference
# (Intercept) -5.93259 -5.17973   -0.75286
# sbp          0.00629  0.00614    0.00015
# tobacco      0.07645  0.06855    0.00791
# ldl          0.16390  0.13664    0.02726
# adiposity    0.01619  0.01601    0.00018
# famhist      0.87514  0.73805    0.13709
# typea        0.03603  0.02629    0.00974
# obesity     -0.05263 -0.03314   -0.01949
# alcohol      0.00013  0.00035   -0.00022
# age          0.04278  0.03238    0.01039
```